# Returning an OleVariant from a function causes an extra reference on the contained IDispatch object that cannot be released

Tags: delphi, memory-leaks, ole, idispatch

I have a function that returns an `OleVariant` that contains an `IDispatch` reference counted object:

```
class function TGrobber.Make: OleVariant;
begin
   Result := (TGrobber.Create as IDispatch);
   // Reference count of IDispatch inside Result at this point is 1
end;
```

And the end of the function, the **RefCount** of the object inside the `OleVariant` is correctly `1`.

But when the `OleVariant` is returned to the caller, the contained object suddenly has a reference count of `2`:

```
var
    grobber: OleVariant;
begin
    grobber := TGrobber.Make; // function that returns an OleVariant
    // Reference count of IDispatch inside OleVariant is now 2 (wrong)
end;
```

This is because after Delphi calls the **Make** function, it calls **VarCopy**:

```
Project2.dpr.147: grobber := TGrobber.Make;
004DA79D 8D55E0           lea edx,[ebp-$20]
004DA7A0 A1DC614D00       mov eax,[$004d61dc]
004DA7A5 E8CAC0FFFF       call TGrobber.Make       <== Creates the object (refcount 1)
004DA7AA 8D55E0           lea edx,[ebp-$20]
004DA7AD B800444E00       mov eax,$004e4400
004DA7B2 E8B128F5FF       call @VarCopy            <== Adds an extra reference, loses the old reference
```

Which means:

- the compiler is adding an extra reference to the returned variable
- while not releasing the old reference
- or alternatively not calling `@VarCopy` at all

How can i ensure that Delphi either:

- destroys the **old** `OleVariant` after it makes a copy
- **not** make a copy of the `OleVariant`, since it doesn't need to make a copy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler does not lose the "old" reference.  The result of `TGrobber.Make()` is first stored in a *hidden* local variable (located at `[ebp-$20]`), which is then assigned to your `grobber` variable (located at `$004e4400`), hence the copy.  So the refcount being 2 is correct. Both variables will be finalized, decrementing the refcount by 2, when they go out of scope when the containing routine exits.

Your code is *effectively* doing the equivalent of this:

```
var
  hidden: OleVariant;
  grobber: OleVariant;
begin
  TGrobber.Make(hidden); // function that returns an OleVariant via a hidden var parameter
  grobber := hidden; // VarCopy(grobber, hidden) is called here
  ...
end; // VarClear(grobber) and VarClear(hidden) are called here...
```